# Delay "Apply Impulse" in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, sprite

I'm coding a game where I have a character following another character and I'd like to make it so that the second character jumps 1 or 2 seconds after the first character jumps. How might I accomplish this?

Here is my method that applies the impulse:

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */

```
    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        fish.physicsBody?.velocity = (CGVectorMake(0,0))
        fisherman.physicsBody?.velocity = (CGVectorMake(0,0))
        fish.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 1000))
        fisherman.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 3000))


            }
}
```

Comment: Are you using GameplayKit for this?

Comment: I'm not using anything except what's included in SpriteKit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already have follow action, you need just to chain it with delay action. There is a class method waitForDuration that allows you to initialize such Action fast.

Here is a code that will do delay and apply impulse afterward:

```
for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        fish.physicsBody?.velocity = (CGVectorMake(0,0))
        fisherman.physicsBody?.velocity = (CGVectorMake(0,0))

        let delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(2.0)

        let fishApplyImpulse = SKAction.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 1000),
               duration sec: 0.0)
        let fishActions = SKAction.sequence([delay, fishApplyImpulse])

        let fishermanApplyImpulse = SKAction.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 3000),
               duration sec: 0.0)


        let fishermanActions = SKAction.sequence([delay, fishermanApplyImpulse])


        fish.runAction(fishActions)
        fisherman.runAction(fishermanActions)
}
```

Code uses SKAction additions for applyImpulse available starting from iOS 9.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you think that you could edit your answer in order to show how I would carry this out? I'm kind of a beginner with SpriteKit.

Comment: Sure. Can you post what you have so far, so I will start not from a blank page?

Comment: How do you use location? Is it just leftover that I should not take into account?

Comment: Oh. That was just in there by default. You can ignore it.

Comment: @kriskendall99 I updated my answer with a code sample. I was not able to run it, as not in front of my computer. So let me know if something will not go as expected :)

Comment: I got the error "'SKAction.Type' does not have a member named 'applyImpulse'."

Comment: @kriskendall99 as I said it was introduced in SpriteKit iOS 9 only. In other scenario you will need to develop custom SKAction with runBlock to wrap the manual logic of impulse applying.

Comment: Oh, yes. I didn't see that. I'll look into custom SKAction development.

Comment: It is actually simple, there is method class func customActionWithDuration(_ seconds: NSTimeInterval, actionBlock block: (SKNode!, CGFloat) -> Void) -> SKAction
and node is available in the block, so you will be able to access physics body.

Comment: Actually, I think it would be even easier to use the action moveByY to add the jump and fall actions.

Comment: Ok, so I am leaving SO for a day. Do not forget to set it as an answer when you validate that sequenced actions approach works for you. Thanks :)